# what is the best way to autowire parent class field in spring?

Tags: java, spring

When I use spring framework, I find something that should be extract, for example, the service component (or member variable that is autowired).
Code show as below:

```
abstract class Payment {

    PaymentService paymentService;

    void setPaymentService(OrderPaymentService paymentService) {
        this.paymentService = paymentService;
    }

}    

@Component
public class CancelPayment extends Payment{
    private OtherService2 otherSerivce2;

    @Autowired
    @Override
    public void setPaymentService(PaymentService paymentService) {
        super.setPaymentService(paymentService);
    }

    @Autowired
    public CancelPayment(OtherService2 s2) {
        this.otherSerivce2 = s2;
    }
}

@Component
public class CreatePayment extends Payment{
    private OtherService1 otherSerivce1;

    @Autowired
    @Override
    public void setPaymentService(PaymentService paymentService) {
        super.setPaymentService(paymentService);
    }

    @Autowired
    public CreatePayment (OtherService1 s1) {
        this.otherSerivce1 = s1;
    }
}
```

As you can see, I use setter injection in each child class. Is this a better practice than autowire their parent's member variable?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the basic idea or structure you show here, but there are specific issues.  You're autowiring three PaymentService objects into the same component.  How do you expect Spring to know which of different beans of type PaymentService it should inject at each of these points?  I assume that you don't want the same bean to be injected into all three inject points, but this is all Spring can do with the code you're showing.  Either you have exactly one PaymentService object, or Spring isn't going to like this code as is.

Comment: ...if you've registered more than one PaymentService bean, believe that Spring is going to complain that it has too many candidate beans of type PaymentService, and so doesn't know what to do. - there are ways around this, like the @Qualifier annotation.

Comment: It's also strange, and I'm not sure legal, to define the **paymentService** variable at both the child and parent levels.  I'm not sure what you think this means in regards to your setter methods calling the superclass's setter, and yet your constructors setting the value directly.  At best, this is very confusing.

Comment: @Steve sorry,to define the paymentService at both the child and parent levels ,that is a clerical mistaken.I will keep it only in parents

Comment: If there is no need of child specific paymentservice(s), then it seems _cleaner_ to have it defined in Parent and inherit?

Comment: @Divs Yes,I think there is no need define paymentService in Child  (it only define in Parent once) ,and children inject paymentService if they want

Comment: ...ah...see you changed things a bit.  Now there's only one PaymentService object.  That's great! - This looks good now!

Comment: @Steve So, If I want extract PaymentService into Parent class , as the code above,That is a good practice right? And it can be better?

Comment: Yeah, that's fine.  This is done all the time.  You have to inject into the beans that you're actually instantiating.  If the storage for something you're injecting happens to be defined in the object's superclass, so be it.  This is great.

Comment: What's a problem to create a constructor in `Payment`?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here are DI guidelines by Spring team:

---

A general guideline, which is recommended by Spring (see the sections on Constructor-based DI or Setter-based DI) is the following:

- For mandatory dependencies or when aiming for immutability, use
  constructor injection
- For optional or changeable dependencies, use setter injection
- Avoid field injection in most cases

---

Now if you are sure you will use PaymentService I would suggest you to use constructor injection in your abstract class like this so object won't instantiate without dependency, also making it more immutable, clearer and thread safe:

```
abstract class Payment {
    PaymentService paymentService;


    public Payment(OrderPaymentService paymentService) {
        this.paymentService = paymentService;
    }
}
```

Then you can simply call super on your extended classes like this:

```
@Component
public class CreatePayment extends Payment{
    private OtherService1 otherSerivce1;

    @Autowired
    public CreatePayment(PaymentService paymentService) {
        super(paymentService);
    }
}
```

This simply allows you to inject parent class using constructor (if paymentService is mandatory).

Comment: This works?  That @Autowired causes Spring to create a CreatePayment bean and pass the PaymentService bean into ITS constructor?  I had no idea that could work. - I knew you could autowire setters and fields in base classes, but not constructors.

Comment: Yeah, actually constructor DI is the most prefered one, this is a bit more complex example because of inheritance but yeah. Field DI is not recommended because of easy code smell and you cannot make it immutable (final), making it less thread safe. With setter, you risk it not being called, therefore instance may not be provided dependency (unless you annotate it with @Required). So yeah, I highly suggest using constructor injection whenever possible.

Comment: @Steve _always_ use constructor autowiring. It's easier to test, you can write validation logic in the ctor rather then writing `PostConstruct` methods and - in my mind the biggest benefit - it provides really clear documentation of the dependencies of a bean.